# Can't get the pixels from ImageData object

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, imagedata

I'm trying to extract pixels from an image using a `canvas` element and the ImageData class, but with little to no success.

My code is:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "<path to PNG image file>";
var context = document.getElementById("my-canvas").getContext("2d");
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 1024, 1024);
console.log(imageData);
```

And the canvas is defined like this:

```
<canvas id ="my-canvas" width="1024" height="1024">
</canvas>
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas) the `data` field should be a 4194304 (1024*1024*4) size array of UInt8. Instead, I get a weirdly nested structure (as the picture shows), and all values are 0. The image is a 1024*1024 PNG image.

Where am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait until your PNG is loaded (ImageData is initialized with zeros):

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = extractPixelsFromPNG;
image.src = "<path to PNG image file>";
var context = document.getElementById("my-canvas").getContext("2d");

function extractPixelsFromPNG() {
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 1024, 1024);
    console.log(imageData);
}
```

Comment: Gets me every time